# Enabling a user to download a file

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on an image gallery, and on the browse image module, I have a download icon. I need it to behave as a download button. When the user clicks on it, they should be presented with save file dialog, or the file should be downloaded using their default browser download set-up.

I tried many ways, but no luck.

- The download Icons appear in a Modal-popup and hence all code is wrapped inside UpdatePannel
- These images are of different formats (jpeg, gif, tif, psd)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/74654/File-Download-in-ASP-NET-and-Tracking-the-Status-o or [Best way to stream files in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/608480/best-way-to-stream-files-in-asp-net)

Comment: `AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename="+ FileName.Name);` is the important part to get a save as dialog ...

Comment: @Sascha This seems to be working the only problem is these icons are inside updatePannel, and hence the postback calls are async, I guess that what stopping the code to execute, but when I put the code in Page_Load it worked fine.

Comment: Glad to hear you're one step further. Maybe this helps in regard to the ajax download: http://groups.google.com/group/ajax-world/browse_thread/thread/b7abc61c1f91376a/af58d68f0b706ae9?hl=en&pli=1

Answer (score 0):

Finally sorted out with :

A) To download a file at Client Location :

```
public void downloadFile(string fileName, string filePath)
    {
        Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename=\"{0}\"", fileName));
        Response.WriteFile(filePath + fileName);
    }
```

B) Since the function triggering controls(`imgDownload`, `imgDownloadPsd`) are wrapped under async call : Add this to Page Load :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page).RegisterPostBackControl(imgDownload);
    ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page).RegisterPostBackControl(imgDownloadPsd);
}
```