# ASP.NET open pdf file in browser using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, pdf

I'm trying to open PDF file in browser that is on fileshare (outside my application folder) using Javascript.

Example:
File location: \fileshare\folder1\folder 2\file.pdf

Chrome browser will open file using this url: file://fileshare/folder1/folder%202/file.pdf

Firefox browser will open file using this url: file://///fileshare/folder1/folder%202/file.pdf

In javascript command for open file in window I'm trying to use this: window.open('file://fileshare/folder1/folder%202/file.pdf);

In Chrome browser instead of file at trying to open that file via that mentioned URL I get "about:blank". If I remove "file:" from URL I get message "404 - File or directory not found.".

How to force browser to use "file:" in URL?

Notice: opening PDF files that are inside application is working fine

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to open file using anchor tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11138136/how-to-open-file-using-anchor-tag)

Comment: It is not the same. I tried using <a href='http://DOMAIN/test1.txt' target='_blank'> for opening file but it is not working. Browser require prefix "file:", not prefix "http:" to open file inside browser.