# Working with files and URLs in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, url

I have the following scenario in ASP.NET application:
Create a file in a temporary directory and return a link to that file.
I implement it as follows:

```
// get URL to create file
var tempDataOperationsDirectory = Server.MapPath("~/temp/DataOperations/foo1.txt");
// Create file
// Create link:
 ButtonViewFile.NavigateUrl = Page.ResolveUrl("~/temp/DataOperations/foo1.txt");
```

The above works. I am wondering if that's a good approach, and what if any alternatives are there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The above works. I am wondering if that's a good approach, and what if
>   any alternatives are there?

It's a good approach and also the recommended one. It will always generate an accurate link. Other approaches I can think of may not be as accurate as this one.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to create that temporary file? If you to create a file dynamically just for a single download, you may want to consider implementing a `HttpHandler` class that can i.e. write a file stream directly to the response returned to the client's browser.

If you want more information about `HttpHandler` in ASP.NET, take a look here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228090.aspx or here [Best way to stream files in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/608480/best-way-to-stream-files-in-asp-net).

Comment: This file is uploaded from a client, and we perform conversions, etc...We "create" it in order to allow the user to re-download the original file.